# How can I filter emails from a distribution list, seperating any addressed to me in particular?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, email-filter

I am on distribution list `+Support`, and want to seperate:

1. Emails that come to me just because I am in `+Support`
2. Emails that have `+Support` in it but also have me in the email TODO.

is this possible in Outlook with a custom rule/filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For 1.**

1. Go to Tools | Rules and Alerts.
2. Select **Check messages when they arrive** and click Next
3. Check **from people or distribution list** option and add +Support email address. Click Next
4. You may want to check the **move it to the specified folder** option and select the folder you want to move your emails. Click Next
5. Click Next and OK on the warning message if you don't select any options here.
6. Name your rule and click Finish

**For 2.**

1. Go to Tools | Rules and Alerts.
2. Select **Check messages when they arrive** and click Next
3. Check **from people or distribution list** option and add +Support email address. Click Next
4. You may want to check the **move it to the specified folder** option and select the folder you want to move your emails. Click Next
5. Check the **except my name is in the To or CC box** and click Next
6. Name your rule and click Finish

**UPDATE:** You may want to check the **Stop processing more rules** for 1. to avoid duplicated emails.